# Error Loading FreeMarker file with SpringMVC 4

Tags: java, css, spring-mvc, freemarker

I'm new in SpringMVC and FreeMarker. I am using eclipse. This is my index.ftl file. My css and image files are in resources folder. The page is loaded on the browser, but the freemarker template is not doing what I expected to see.

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 

<#import "spring.ftl" as spring />   

<head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
       href="<@spring.url '/freemarker/css/style.css'/>"/>

       <title>Spring MVC Blog</title>

    </head>

    <body>

       <div id="image">
        <img src="freemarker/image/blog-logo.png">
        </div>

        <div id="nav">
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>       
         <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>       
         <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>       
         <li><a href="#">Posts</a></li>       
         <li><a href="#">Create Posts</a></li>       
         <li><a href="#">Users</a></li>         
         <li>
        <div id="logged-in-info"> <span>Hello, <b>(user)</b></span>
        <form method="post" action="menu.html">
        <input type="submit" value="Logout"/>
        </form>
             </div>  
        </li>         
        </ul>

</div>


    </body>
</html>
```

return

My Servlet root is defined as:

```xml
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>

    <bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
        <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/freemarker/" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
        <property name="cache" value="true" />
        <property name="prefix" value="" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".ftl" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: I can't figure out what's wrong here! Perhaps I need to change something in Servlet file. Please, any tip?

Comment: Can you provide details as to what it is doing?

Comment: Sean Carrol, basically, when I run the program only the list of items are rendered in the web browser, that is, Home, Login and so on... Moreover, I have two separated files located in src/main/resource: folder css (style.css) and folder image(blog-log.png). What I want is to use these two files inside my Freemarker template file index.ftl, so that I can format my page with css file and respectively include the image on the page of my web application(SpringMVC blog with Freemarker).

Comment: So you are getting 404s loading the CSS and image files?

Comment: Sean Carroll, I am not getting this error. According to the example that I have provided above, can you, please, demonstrate an example of how to include those css file and an image inside index.ftl? I've seen so far many examples, but unfortunately nothing is working.]